# Installing Ghost on MacOS: 'ghost install local' produces 'Response code 401 (Unauthorized)' midway through install process

Tags: node.js, ghost-blog

I'm trying to install Ghost locally to evaluate for a project.  I followed the [instructions](https://ghost.org/docs/install/local/) but when I run

```
ghost install local
```

inside an empty folder, I get the following error:

> Message: 'Response code 401 (Unauthorized)'

[image]

I tried `sudo ghost install local` but with the same results.  I also changed the folder permissions to allow everyone to read/write to the folder.  Same results.

### Edit

I changed the Node version to 10.x, which was recommended to me by ghost.  I get the following (similar) error.  It seems to fail in `got`?

```
Debug Information:
    OS: Mac OS X, v10.14.5
    Node Version: v10.19.0
    Ghost-CLI Version: 1.13.1
    Environment: development
    Command: 'ghost install local'
An error occurred.
Message: 'Response code 401 (Unauthorized)'

Stack: HTTPError: Response code 401 (Unauthorized)
    at EventEmitter.ee.on.res (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/download/node_modules/got/index.js:482:24)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at getResponse (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/download/node_modules/got/index.js:320:5)
    at Immediate.setImmediate (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/download/node_modules/got/index.js:147:6)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
Path: /axags/api/npm/virtual-bcn-node/ghost/-/ghost-3.5.0.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a question of connection at our end, `.npmrc` settings that interfered with the process.

Comment: IMO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60165042/is-it-possible-to-combine-optional-chaining-with-map-in-javascript is a fine question, not sure why it got downvotes

Comment: Want to undelete it? I wouldn't be surprised at all if it becomes more popular later, it's a *really* nice pattern, better than the other options we have currently

Comment: @CertainPerformance -- Perhaps because optional chaining is to be used with objects.  I was using it with arrays.  I removed it because I thought I was missing the obvious.   Although I suppose an array _is_ an object -- not sure why it got downvotes.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, undeleted, I guess I'll take the downvotes if they come....