# Is it possible to combine optional chaining with arrays and map (in Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-next

I recently learned about [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in Javascript and have been making use of it in a React/NodeJS project.  Works great.

I noticed I have been using it with arrays `map`, even without thinking about it much -- it seemed a natural use (here `items` is an array, or possibly `undefined`)

```
        {items?.map(postListItem => ....
```

That is, it will map if `items` exists, but not if `items` is `undefined`, but would avoid any run-time errors if I were to call `map` on `undefined`

Nonetheless I don't know if this is an acceptable use or whether I'm mis-using optional chaining.  I searched for an answer but as of yet haven't been able to find one, which makes me suspect I'm mis-using it.  Any info much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a nifty shortcut. If it works, go for it

Comment: why the curly? if an object, then a key is missing.

Comment: @NinaScholz It's JSX syntax - `{` can be put at some positions (like as a prop, or a child of an element) to insert what the following JS expression evaluates to. Eg `<div>{ true ? 'foo' : 'bar' }</div>` results in `<div>foo</div>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the chaining fails, the expression will evaluate to `undefined`.

When a child is evaluated to `undefined`, it [just won't render](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).

Conditional rendering is already quite a common strategy. Previously, when you have something that may be an array or may be `undefined`, and you want to map *if* there's an array, you would have had to do something like:

```
{ items && items.map( ...
```

This works because, if `items` is `undefined`, the whole expression will be evaluated to `undefined`, and no rendering will happen, and no errors will be thrown.

Using optional chaining works exactly the same way, except that it's more concise. So yes, this is a perfectly valid thing to do.

Optional chaining is [stage 4](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining), so you can count on it working reliably.

Arrays [are objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048371/are-javascript-arrays-primitives-strings-objects). But optional chaining isn't *only* for objects - it can work for anything which may have a property or method. Eg `const bar = foo?.toFixed(2)` will work fine if `foo` is `null`, `undefined`, or a number (numbers have a `toFixed` method).

Answer (score 16):

See answer here regarding the typescript usage.  You need a period for array null safe Optional Chaining.

```
    this.mostRecentMfaAttempt = this.verificationsAttempts?.content?.[0]
```

[How to use optional chaining with array in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59623674/how-to-use-optional-chaining-with-array-in-typescript)

[Using optional chaining operator for object property access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780817/using-optional-chaining-operator-for-object-property-access)

Comment: Maybe worth noting that this crashes if the array exists but is empty.

Answer (score 3):

The optional chaining way to your problem is:

```
{items?.map?.(postListItem => ....)
```

Read more here: [MDN Web Docs: Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: This could help if one doesn't know if `items` is an array or not, but if one is sure it will either be an array or `undefined`, there's no need for the second `?.`

Comment: True but since he said he just started learning about optional chaining, I was just showing of how to do it using only optional chaining, not necessarily the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from the MongoDB database by filtering use below system.

```js
cars.filter(car => car.email === user.email)?.map(car => {
    return (
        <tr key={car._id}>
            <td>{car.userName}</td>
            <td className=''>{car.email}</td>
            <td>{car.name}</td>
            <td><img src={car.img} alt="" /></td>
        </tr>
    )
})
```

Comment: Please edit your question and place code in `code` blocks properly, and maintain indentation.